# AdMob is throwing Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1) on Phonegap 3

Tags: java, android, cordova, admob

I am getting this error in logs and the app crashes:

```
15:53:22.518: A/libc(25934): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 25934 (s.testapp)
```

**The error fired when**:

- I press/tap/slide over the admob banner.
- Turn the mobile from landscape to portrait and viceversa.
- Tap/press/slide fingers over the app (outside the banner).

I am using SDK GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1 with Phonegap 3.0 on Android 4.1.2, I know is admob because when I disable it, the problem is gone.

Here is the code:

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxx");
LinearLayout layout = super.root;
layout.addView(adView);        
layout.setHorizontalGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();   
//request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Comment: The JVM uses the `SIGSEGV` signal and a few others for its own purposes. Is the program continuing normally, or is it terminating abruptly?

Comment: The program closes abruptly and the last error log is the Fatal Signal 11, the program run normally if I comment the code of AdMob, I mean if no banner is loaded.

Comment: I posted a bug report directly on cordova.apache.org:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4594?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13742288#comment-13742288

Answer (score 4):

I have noticed that my app crashed too but only for animated ads.

Then, I turned the `android:hardwareAccelerated` to `false` in the manifest file in the application tag. My app is working fine now.