# Android admob viewpager Fatal error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, admob

I have a not pretty nice problem with Admob and my android application.

Let's explain:

I use an AdView Banner in fragment 1 inside a ViewPager.
When i switch to fragment 2 , viewpager keep fragment 1 as usual but the AdView inside Fragment 1 still refresh itself and cause an app crash with this error:

A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000038 (code=1), thread 8335

I don't know which app structure i need to used to be out of this crash.

I haven't found how to disable auto refresh ads.

I can't tell to fragment 1 to destroy its adview cause no one state is fired (onPause, onDestroy) when i switch to fragment 2.

I want to keep the viewpager but have you some best practices to implement AdView inside fragment of viewpager without have this error?

Thanks a lot for reading my post and any tips you'll give to me.

Comment: it seems like memory error. can you please post crash logs here.

Comment: i only have A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000038 (code=1), thread 8335

Comment: possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20192013/2298357

Comment: its seams to works , the admob still refresh but without fatal error, thank you, how can i do without use this tips ?

Comment: Best practice is attach each lifecycle callbacks with AdView.please follow https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView

Comment: in my viewpager the lifecycle of fragment never launch (onPause, OnDestroy) they are configured to keep when i swipe with viewpager